# Passing shell variables to ssh

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ssh

I read the other postings on passing variables in remote ssh, but those solutions don't seem to work for me.

Here is my situation: I'm populating the values of my variables throughout my shell script (on a local machine), which are then used on **another** system via ssh. I understand why this isn't working, but I'd like to find a way to use values in a local shell on another system via ssh.

```
BUILD_SERVER="my_server"
ANOTHER_SERVER="my_server2"
ssh $USERNAME@$BUILD_SERVER << 'ENDSSH'

echo "$BUILD_SERVER"
echo "$ANOTHER_SERVER"

ENDSSH
```

When I run this code, these variables are null. Is there any way to pass through the values to ssh?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out.  On the line where I was doing the following:

```
ssh $USERNAME@$BUILD_SERVER << 'ENDSSH'
```

I removed the single quotes and it now interprets allow of my local variables.  If I want to use a variable on the remote server I just escape them with a "\"

```
ssh $USERNAME@$BUILD_SERVER << ENDSSH

echo $BUILD_SERVER     # echos the local server variable
LOCAL_SERVER="local_server"

echo \$LOCAL_SERVER    # echos the remote server variable

ENDSSH
```

Comment: So local is my local machine and remote the server? I have a similar problem: 
`ssh -p $deployServerPort -t $deployServerUser@$deployServerIp "sudo bash \"$deployShellScript\" 'true'"` my problem is, that the `String: true` is not recognized. I want to pass `true` to  the script in `$deployShellScript`.

Comment: @AndiGiga in my solution the `$LOCAL_SERVER` variable is on your local machine, or the machine that is calling ssh, and `\$LOCAL_SERVER` is that variable expanded on the remote machine.  I think you need to escape true as well.  (e.g. `\"true\"`)

Comment: I tried to escape it as well, but my script didn't take it. But now I got why, it's an error within the script. Still Thx